# OCR Android application that is using Tesseract

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to build an OCR application on Android using Tesseract, but when I save the picture the application crushes.

I've build the photo capture with the tutorial *[Simple Android Photo Capture](http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/simple-android-photo-capture/)*
and the OCR function with the guide *[Making a Simple OCR Android App using Tesseract](http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/)*.

This is the code I'm using:

```
package com.mmm.pitter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.mmm.pitter.R;
import com.googlecode.tesseract.android.*;
import com.googlecode.leptonica.android.*;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PitterActivity extends Activity
{
    protected Button _button;
    protected ImageView _image;
    protected TextView _field;
    protected String _path;
    protected boolean _taken;

    protected static final String PHOTO_TAKEN = "photo_taken";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        _image = ( ImageView ) findViewById( R.id.image );
        _field = ( TextView ) findViewById( R.id.field );
        _button = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.button );
        _button.setOnClickListener( new ButtonClickHandler() );

        _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/images/make_machine_example.jpg";
    }

    public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        public void onClick( View view ){
            Log.i("MakeMachine", "ButtonClickHandler.onClick()" );
            startCameraActivity();
        }
    }

    protected void startCameraActivity()
    {
        Log.i("MakeMachine", "startCameraActivity()" );
        File file = new File( _path );
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );

        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
        intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );

        startActivityForResult( intent, 0 );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        Log.i( "MakeMachine", "resultCode: " + resultCode );
        switch( resultCode )
        {
            case 0:
                Log.i( "MakeMachine", "User cancelled" );
                break;

            case -1:
                try {
                    onPhotoTaken();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    protected void onPhotoTaken() throws IOException
    {
        Log.i( "MakeMachine", "onPhotoTaken" );

        _taken = true;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( _path, options );

        _image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        _field.setVisibility( View.GONE );

        //_path = path to the image to be OCRed
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(_path);
        int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        int rotate = 0;

        switch (exifOrientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotate = 90;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotate = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotate = 270;
                break;
        }

        if (rotate != 0) {
            int w = bitmap.getWidth();
            int h = bitmap.getHeight();

            // Setting pre rotate
            Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
            mtx.preRotate(rotate);

            // Rotating Bitmap & convert to ARGB_8888, required by tess
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, false);
            bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        }

        TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
        // DATA_PATH = Path to the storage
        // lang for which the language data exists, usually "eng"
        baseApi.init(""sdcard/tesseract/tessdata", "eng");
        baseApi.setImage(bitmap);
        String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
        System.out.println(recognizedText);
        baseApi.end();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState( Bundle savedInstanceState){
        Log.i( "MakeMachine", "onRestoreInstanceState()");
        if( savedInstanceState.getBoolean( PitterActivity.PHOTO_TAKEN ) ) {
            try {
                onPhotoTaken();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState( Bundle outState ) {
        outState.putBoolean( PitterActivity.PHOTO_TAKEN, _taken );
    }
}
```

And this is the log:

```
10-13 23:13:51.191: I/MakeMachine(29787): ButtonClickHandler.onClick()
10-13 23:13:51.191: I/MakeMachine(29787): startCameraActivity()
10-13 23:13:51.851: D/CLIPBOARD(29787): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
10-13 23:13:51.866: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(29787): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
10-13 23:14:07.431: I/MakeMachine(29787): onRestoreInstanceState()
10-13 23:14:07.431: I/MakeMachine(29787): resultCode: -1
10-13 23:14:07.431: I/MakeMachine(29787): onPhotoTaken
10-13 23:14:07.431: I/System.out(29787): Not a DRM File, opening notmally
10-13 23:14:07.436: E/JHEAD(29787): can't open
10-13 23:14:07.436: D/dalvikvm(29787): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.mmm.pitter/lib/liblept.so 0x4154e9a0
10-13 23:14:07.436: D/dalvikvm(29787): Added shared lib /data/data/com.mmm.pitter/lib/liblept.so 0x4154e9a0
10-13 23:14:07.446: D/dalvikvm(29787): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.mmm.pitter/lib/libtess.so 0x4154e9a0
10-13 23:14:07.456: D/dalvikvm(29787): Added shared lib /data/data/com.mmm.pitter/lib/libtess.so 0x4154e9a0
10-13 23:14:07.471: D/AndroidRuntime(29787): Shutting down VM
10-13 23:14:07.471: W/dalvikvm(29787): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c5b1f8)
10-13 23:14:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29787): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 23:14:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29787): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.mmm.pitter/com.mmm.pitter.PitterActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.mmm.pitter/com.mmm.pitter.PitterActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data path must contain subfolder tessdata!
10-13 23:14:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29787):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2456)
10-13 23:14:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29787):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2484)
10-13 23:14:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29787):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1998)
10-13 23:14:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29787):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3363)
10-13 23:14:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29787):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:127)
10-13 23:14:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29787):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1163)
10-13 23:14:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29787):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-13 23:14:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29787):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-13 23:14:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29787):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
10-13 23:14:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29787):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 23:14:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29787):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-13 23:14:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29787):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
10-13 23:14:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29787):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
10-13 23:14:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29787):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-13 23:14:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29787): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.mmm.pitter/com.mmm.pitter.PitterActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data path must contain subfolder tessdata!
10-13 23:14:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29787):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2992)
10-13 23:14:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29787):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2443)
10-13 23:14:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29787):     ... 13 more
10-13 23:14:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29787): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data path must contain subfolder tessdata!
10-13 23:14:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29787):     at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.init(TessBaseAPI.java:178)
10-13 23:14:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29787):     at com.mmm.pitter.PitterActivity.onPhotoTaken(PitterActivity.java:146)
10-13 23:14:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29787):     at com.mmm.pitter.PitterActivity.onActivityResult(PitterActivity.java:88)
10-13 23:14:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29787):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4649)
10-13 23:14:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29787):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2988)
10-13 23:14:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29787):     ... 14 more
10-13 23:19:32.376: I/Process(29787): Sending signal. PID: 29787 SIG: 9
```

Comment: does this blurb way at the end of one of your exception messages clear anything up?: "Data path must contain subfolder tessdata!"

Comment: I've changed the data path to the subfolder tessdata on line 148, but it still says the it must contain it. where do i need to change it

Comment: Where should I add tessdata folder.? In libs or assets.?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to put the data files in the `tessdata` directory, and specify the *parent directory* of `tessdata` in your `init()` method:

```
baseApi.init("/mnt/sdcard/tesseract", "eng");
```

Comment: can you plz provide the activity xml file ??

Comment: Where should I add tessdata folder.? In libs or assets.?

Comment: @Frankenstein: I kept in "assests"

Comment: @rmtheis how to read MICR code do you have any idea about that  please see [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279271/android-how-to-recognize-micr-codes) I have copied `mcr.traineddata` in asset folder but still its not recognizing MICR codes

Comment: How will that get there when user installs OCR application on device... should I copy it there by code ?

Answer (score 1):

```
baseApi.init(""sdcard/tesseract/tessdata", "eng");
```

is replaced by

```
baseApi.init(""sdcard/tesseract/", "eng");
```

with tessaract folder must include tessdata folder. Because, when you compile, the path will add "tessdat" with the line

```
File tessdata = new File(datapath + "tessdata");
```

in the init() function.
And why has the slash ("/") at the end of the path, the below comment will help you:

> The datapath must be the name of the parent directory of tessdata and
>   must end in / . Any name after the last / will be stripped. The
>   language is (usually) an ISO 639-3 string or `null` will
>   default to eng.  It is entirely safe (and eventually will be efficient
>   too) to call Init multiple times on the same instance to change
>   language, or just to reset the classifier.

You can see at [website](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/blob/master/tess-two/src/com/googlecode/tesseract/android/TessBaseAPI.java) with the comment for init() function.
I hope them will help you.

Answer (score -2):

tesseract library is as .zip for windows, as .tar.gz for linux user.

```
baseApi.init("/mnt/sdcard/tesseract/tessdata/eng.traineddata", "eng");
```

Please tell me if it runs for you.