# How to recognize MICR codes in Android

Tags: android, tesseract, micr

I am trying to find the way to OCR the MICR codes from document. For that I used [Tesseract](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two) library, Using this I got success in recognizing texts but when it comes to MICR it fails to recognize that.

Here is the sample MICR image which I want to read:

[image]

This is a `MICR E-13B` fonts ([more info](http://www.micrencodingfonts.com/)).

So is there any open source library to recognize MICR codes for Android? I found [Leadtools](http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/ocr/micr.htm) SDK which provides this functionality but that is paid.

Comment: I'm using tesseract 3.02 do you have mcr.traineddata for it? can you share it?

Comment: How do you exclude the special charaters

Comment: Well I managed to do that in Java code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Tesseract with [`mcr.traineddata`](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/tesseract-ocr/micr/tesseract-ocr/obWI4cz8rXg/_Yl8RuCeJAkJ) language data file.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have `copied micr,traineddata` in appropriate directory but still its not reading MICR text.is there anything else to do get this working.

Comment: Did you specify the language parameter `-l mcr`?

Comment: in Linux system using command line it works for me too.
do you have any idea about how to get this working with Android application ?

Comment: On Android, you need to install the language data file on the device and specify the path to its parent directory in init(), for example, `baseApi.init("/mnt/sdcard/tesseract", "mcr");`

Comment: @rmtheis I'll try this and let you know in case of any query. Thanks for the help BTW.

Comment: @rmtheis is that possible to initialize two languages in tesseract  ? I tried with `baseApi.init("/mnt/sdcard/tesseract", "eng"); baseApi.init("/mnt/sdcard/tesseract", "mcr");` but its initializes only mcr not eng.

Comment: Yes--use `baseApi.init("/mnt/sdcard/tesseract", "eng+mcr");`

Comment: i used mcr.traineddata language data file but its not working.

Comment: In my case, the language mcr works but recognition is not very good :(

Answer (score 0):

If you try to recognize stubs and cheques, you can give a look to MICR and OCR languages file from https://github.com/BigPino67/Tesseract-MICR-OCR