# How to recognize MICR codes?

Tags: visual-c++, tesseract, micr

I want to write a c++ program that can be used to scan MICR codes same as -([Android : How to recognize MICR codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279271/android-how-to-recognize-micr-codes)). I have used tesseract before to scan texts from a image and it worked fine but it fails miserably and gives me stupid results when i scan MICR codes. I would really appreciate if someone can advise me any links or suggestions on how to scan MICR code in Windows using tesseract or any other library.

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You could use OpenCV to write your own OCR system. It implements the k-nearest neighbor algorithm that could be used to recognize arbitrary characters (characters of the MICR in this case). I did something like this using the Java bindings of OpenCV and it gave me good results.

This post got me started with the idea : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9620295/2644645

**edit**

Roughly, you could do :

1. Find a way to extract individual character from you image.
2. Normalize these characters (for example if the point of view or the distance vary).
3. Manually create your training set for the k-nearest neighbor algorithm. You should also consider a way to save/load the data (I think OpenCV can do this).
4. Finally, you can feed unknown characters into the algorithm and it will give you the best match (if k=1) in your training set. Be sure to consider the returned vector *dist*, as it gives you an idea if it's a good match or not.

Comment: You should include the relevant text from the link as there is no guarantee that it will still be alive when someone goes to click it.

Comment: @ txtflood - Thank you for your reply. So, i should use the K-nearest neighbor algorithm? Is there any link which shows how to implement the K-nearest algorithm?

Comment: Well, it sure is more work than using a OCR library. The algorithm is already implemented by OpenCV, there's an online documentation for the class.

Comment: @txtflood :- Thanks for your reply. So, what do you advise me? I have to complete this project within the next 7 days. So, what suggestions would you give me?