# Preprocess image in GPUImage before ocr

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, tesseract, gpuimage

I want to Pre Process this image in Apple Ios,
which kind of filters we can apply for this kind of images.
I want to remove double quotes characters before and after numbers numbers as well as last character as i marked in boxes.

I have tried whitelisting

```
tessrect.charwhitelist="0123456789";
```

and

```
tessrect.blacklist="\":";
```

I have used GPUImage lib for preprocessing.

[image: Image Sample]

Comment: I don't know anything about Apple Ios stuff but I would suggest to search for all characters with some segmentation methods(adaptive threshold) and maybe filter on blob size. I can imagine the blobs of the quotes being a smaller size than the digits.

Comment: What does Tesseract return ? It might be more effective to perform OCR on the characters as they stand and discard whatever was decoded for them (hopefully non-digits).

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes but Tesseract some times detects it as numbers or some times as characters.

Comment: Is the text layout fixed ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes this is one of Bank Cheque image.

Comment: Then isn't it enough to discard the first, eighth and eighteenth characters ?

Comment: The characters are `U+2446 OCR BRANCH BANK IDENTIFICATION` and `U+2448 OCR DASH` [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_Character_Recognition_%28Unicode_block%29). You could try training this font as described [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract#training-procedure).

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279271/android-how-to-recognize-micr-codes) might be interesting for you.