# how to recognize correct micr code in android

Tags: android

I am trying to recognize MICR codes on cheques using Tessaract library in android.

For this I have downloaded 'mcr.traineddata' and saved it in assests. Using this  MICR code not  recognize that.
mcr.traineddata file downloaded here

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/tesseract-ocr/micr/tesseract-ocr/obWI4cz8rXg/_Yl8RuCeJAkJ

it show wrong micr code

```
    TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
    baseApi.setDebug(true);
    baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, "mcr");
    baseApi.setImage(bitmap);

    String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();

    baseApi.end();
```

Any ideas, suggestions and advice will be appreciated.

Comment: i tried many link like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279271/android-how-to-recognize-micr-codes but i can't get correct micr code..anyone have any ideas.