# Building google tesseract with NDK for using in android studio

Tags: android, android-ndk, tesseract

I am trying to make an simple OCR app using google tesseract. For this purpose, i am following this [tutorial](http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/#comment-194421). But running **ant release** command, i am getting an error. The error message is like this:

> Buildfile: C:\Users\Pial-PC\Desktop\tesseract\eyes-two\build.xml
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   C:\Users\Pial-PC\Desktop\tesseract\eyes-two\build.xml:46: sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project' or to inject it through an env var
>
> Total time: 1 second

My question is how can i remove this problem? Is **ant release** actually needed to build tesseract in order to use it in android studio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you didn't run `android update project --path .` to generate the `local.properties` file.

But there's an easier way-- as of a recent update, you can follow the [instructions](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two#usage) to include the OCR engine in your app as a pre-compiled binary. To use the current version, add

```
compile 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:5.4.0'
```

to the `dependencies` section of your app's `app/build.gradle`.

Comment: after adding this to the dependencies section of  my app's **build.gradle** can i call the api like this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/840623/Android-Character-Recognition) explained in **Code Project** ?

Comment: Yes. The path for init() in the tutorial is wrong though -- see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12880105/667810) for the correct way to format the path parameter there.

Comment: In **GitHub** link says that **A v3.02+ trained data file for a language. Data files must be extracted to the Android device in a subdirectory named tessdata.**
Where i will make the tessdata subdirectory in android studio? Or while grade was building,trained data files were downloaded too?

Comment: You need to manually download the trained data, and install those files on your device manually, or add code to your app to install them programmatically. [Save](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) to app-private external storage.